# Нелинейная форма получения данных из базы

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, sqlite3

Есть база с 3 таблицами: люди, автомобили, связи людей с автомобилями (у каждого человека может быть много автомобилей)

```
create table peoples (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 f text,
 i text,
 o text,
 ...
);

create table cars (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 car text,
 ...
);

create table relations (
 id integer primary key autoincrement,
 fio_id integer,
 car_id integer
);
```

```
class peoples {
 public $fio = [
  'f' => null,
  'i' => null,
  'o' => null
 ];
 public $cars = [];
}
```

При получении данных из базы данных всегда данные приходят в линейном виде.

Есть ли способ получить их сразу в виде класса который предложен выше. Или можно только вручную разложить всё после получения?

С одной стороны логично, ведь база данных "не знает" что какие-то поля связаны, но с другой стороны если этих полей очень много, будет тяжеловато.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Штука, связывающая таблицы из базы и классы из программы, называется ORM

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону ActiveRecord